# Bootstrap Tags Input events not firing when used with element created via AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I've got a page with a form, which is created via an AJAX call, and which contains a [Bootstrap Tags Input element](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/). The following code, which attempts to take advantage of standard Tags Input events, has no effect:

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('itemAdded itemRemoved', '.bootstrap-tagsinput input',  function(e) {
        alert('triggered');
        // call some function
    });

    // after the form is generated via the AJAX call, the tags input is 'refreshed'
    ...
       $('.input_tags').tagsinput('refresh');
    ...
</script>
```

**HTML** (this is the standard HTML that's generated when the Tags Input plugin is applied; 'tag...' elements are added/remove in correspondence to the user adding/removing tags from the input field):

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
   <span class="tag label label-info">
   ...
   <span class="tag label label-info">
   <input type="text" size="4">
</div>
```

Any ideas as to what could be going wrong here, and how to fix it?

Comment: On what action it should trigger?? And can you show us your html?

Comment: @kernallora - I've added the HTML that's present when the page is fully loaded (this is distinct from the HTML that's generated by the server, because the tags plugin changes the HTML code). It should trigger when a tag is removed or added: `itemAdded`, `itemRemoved`.

Comment: If you have found a solution, post an answer to your question it will be easier to understand.

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux - done.

Answer (score 1):

Once try like this, it should works.

Add id for input element.

```
 <div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
   <span class="tag label label-info">
   ...
   <span class="tag label label-info">
   <input type="text" id="idInput" size="4">
</div>
```

You  event should be like this

```
 $("#idInput").on('itemAdded', function(event) {
    console.log('item added : '+event.item);
});
$("#idInput").on('itemRemoved', function(event) {
    console.log('item removed : '+event.item);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, kernal. I've solved the issue. I'll append my solution to my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that I've found:

Below the visible input within the 'bootstrap-tagsinput' div element, a hidden input field exists which has the attributes of the input field which was generated server-side, and to which .tagsinput() was applied. Events should be associated with this field, rather than with the visible input that is within the 'bootstrap-tagsinput' div.